# Creating truth tables

Tags: boolean-computation

I want to write a module in *Mathematica* that receives a Boolean function `f`. The module should write on screen:

- Truth table of function `f`
- Boolean expression which contains only operator NOR
- Minimization in DNF for the function f

This is my try

```
n = Input["Insert function"]
Module[{t}, 
  t = n; 
  Print[t]]
TableForm[
  BooleanTable[{t}], 
  TableHeadings -> {None, {t}}]

Table[BooleanConvert[{t}, fm], {fm, {"NOR"}}]

expr = t

BooleanMinimize[expr = t, "DNF"]
```

Comment: Hi ! Please format your code properly -- you can find more information in the help centre.

Comment: Hello i have problems because module should receive from the function and then write on screen but i don't know how to do it. My solution is bad but that's all i got.

Comment: I was about to format your question earlier, but you kept editing it with extra useless spacing, wiping out my edit twice. So I decided not to do it. Please do it yourself and bear in mind it is not helpful to simply repeat the question again in comments like you did above.

Comment: can you give me a link of this kind of question?

Comment: Look at the example on this guide by Wolfram: [Create Truth Tables](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/example/CreateTruthTables.html). Also, you seem never to use the $n$ function that you obtained as input. The rest of the code works well, in that it generates a table and generally does what it says on the tin. Maybe you should prune your code to represent the part you have trouble with.

Comment: Hello MarcoB. I don't know how to use input i wrote one function and after that the code was for that specific function. But the problem is i need to write module and input and the rest of the code to work for the input if you have some advice please help.

Comment: I do have advice - go to the documentation centre and search for those keywords you are throwing around, like *module*, *function*, etc.

Comment: Please can someone help me i did some improvement but i still think that's not it

Answer (score 3):

First I will define function that produces the output you want given a Boolean function.

```
boolStuff[f_Function] :=
  (Clear[x, y];
   Column[{
     TableForm[BooleanTable[{x, y, f[x, y]}, {x, y}],
       TableHeadings -> {None, {x, y, f[x, y]}}],
     BooleanConvert[f[x, y], NOR],
     BooleanMinimize[f[x, y]]}])
```

then

```
boolStuff[Function[{x, y}, Implies[x, y]]]
```

gives

[image: implies]

You can also enter functions in the more concise pure function from:

```
boolStuff[#1 && #2 &]
```

which gives

[image: and]

If you want to enter the function interactively, you can evaluate

```
boolStuff[Input["Insert function"]]
```