# How to create BooleanTables in Mathematica for $A \not \Rightarrow B$ and $A \Leftrightarrow B$?

Tags: boolean-computation

How to create BooleanTables in Mathematica for $A \not \Rightarrow B$ and $A \Leftrightarrow B$ ?

Comment: Take a look at the functions `Implies`, `Not` and `Equivalent`. You can then create a simple table with `Table`

Comment: You may find [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85940/3066) useful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating truth tables](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84208/creating-truth-tables)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
head = {{"A", "B", "A does not imply B"}};
tab = Flatten[
      Table[{A, B, Not[Implies[A, B]]}, {A, {True, False}}, {B, {True, False}}]
      , 1];
Join[head, tab] // TableForm
```

[image]

Comment: That works. Thanks.

Comment: @Aronas you are welcome :D since you are new, dont forget to accept an answer if it solved your problem. That is important for everybody who might need this at some point.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct the truth tables with

```
Labeled[#, "Table of ¬⇒", Top] &@
   TableForm[#, TableHeadings -> Boole@{{True, False}, {True, False}}] &@
 Outer[Boole@Not@Implies[#1, #2] &, {True, False}, {True, False}]
```

[image]

and

```
Labeled[#, "Table of ⇔", Top] &@
   TableForm[#, 
    TableHeadings -> Boole@{{True, False}, {True, False}}] &@
 Outer[Boole@Equivalent[#1, #2] &, {True, False}, {True, False}]
```

[image]